# Hide custom css scrollbar in only mobile?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm not sure whether this is possible, but using webkit I made a custom scrollbar that doesn't show up on mobile, so there is a gap on the right side of the screen where it should be (instead, the default chrome one appears). It shows up perfectly fine on desktop.

Is there anyway of: 
a) making this scrollbar show up on chrome mobile browser. 
b) hiding the custom scrollbar on mobile only, so the gap doesn't appear, but also allowing the custom scrollbar to show on desktop simultaneously.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
width:5px;
background-color:black;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width:5px;
background-color:white;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: white; 
}
```

Comment: Just try [CSS media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). :)

Answer (score 0):

If you whant only css solution, you can use media queries like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 736px) {

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
  ::-webkit-scrollbar,
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    //default styles
  }

}
```

But if you want to detect touch screen, you need to use some js, my favorite lib for this task is [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JS, and want to support tablets as well, you can check whether the device supports hovering using a media query.

```
@media (hover: hover) {
  *::-webkit-scrollbar { /*custom styles*/ }
  *::-webkit-scrollbar-track { /*custom styles*/ }
  *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { /*custom styles*/ }
  *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { /*custom styles*/ } 
}
```

(That way you don't have to set an **arbitrary** max-device-width threshold.)

Hovering in that context means **convenient** hovering. Some mobiles and tablets support rudimentary hovering by a long touch, but those don't count:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover#none